# How to interface Mongodb database with web application running on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have installed Mongodb 3.0 database instance on AWS EC2 using AWS CloudFormation.
I have following 2 queries :-

1. During the installation, I chose the instance type as 't2.micro'
   and if I'm not wrong, this should be covered up under AWS Free-Tier
   usage for evaluation purpose. But may I know where exactly, I can
   see and confirm that my instance is running under free-tier usage?
2. I have deployed a web application too using Elastic Beanstalk
       services and it is running fine with one of the EC2 instances. I can
       test my application on cloud very well with static data (means no DB
       interface yet). I want to open the port between my Web App on 1 EC2
       instance and MongoDB (which I installed recently) running on another
       EC2 instance. Can somebody advise on this?

Thank you